# Lagrange Remainder and Intervals of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

(a) Determine the largest interval centered at $c=0$ on which we can be sure that $\lvert \cos(x) -(1-\frac{x^2}{2})\rvert < 10^{-6}$

(b) Let $T_n(x)$ denote the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ for $\cos x$ at $c=0$. Find the smallest value for $n$ for which we can be sure that $\lvert\cos x - T_n(x)\rvert < 10^{-6}$ for all $x$ with $\lvert x\rvert \le1$.

For the first part I took the $\cos x$ as a series and subtracted off the first two terms to get what is in absolute value. From here I am not sure how to progress. The radius of convergence would be the same as $\cos x$ $(R=1)$ wouldn't it? Does this mean I am looking for an $x$ value less than $1$? this implies that I am looking for an $x$ value less than $1$ but how do I go about finding this?

Comment: You talk about Lagrange's form of the remainder. Why don't you use it? BTW, the series for cosine has infinite convergence radius.

Comment: So should I find $R_2(x)$ and then solve $R_2(x) <10^-6$ for $x$?

Comment: That is the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\cos{x}$ has an alternating Taylor expansion. Thus we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty a_ix^i\leq \sum_{i=0}^n(a_ix^i)+|a_{n+1}x^{n+1}|$$

$$|f(x)-T_n(x)|=|\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i-\sum_{j=0}^na_jx^j|\leq |a_{n+1}x^{n+1}|$$

For 1, you know $a_{n+1}$ and have a fixed $n$, so you just need to find the largest $x$ value that fits the given inequality.

For 2, you are given that $|x|\leq 1$, which is largest for $x=1$. Thus the second equation reduces to

$$|f(x)-T_n(1)|=|\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i-\sum_{j=0}^na_j|\leq |a_{n+1}|$$

Which value of $n$ makes the inequality hold?

Comment: So looking this and the comments above I need to look at 3rd term in the expansion. I know the coefficient and the exponent, so I need to solve for x. I have $\frac{x^4}{4!} < 10^-6$. Therefore $x=(\frac{24}{10^6})^\frac{1}{4}$ (For the first part)

Comment: Correct! How about the second part?

NB: You can only bound the error by the last term because it alternates. This does not work in general. In the general case, you have to consider $\int_0^xf^{(n+1)}(t)\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt$

This second formula is obviously much more unwieldly, so use the alternating series formula when you can.

Comment: For the second part, going through the motions I got $n=10$. It just comes down to plugging in values into $\frac{1}{n!}$ until you get the desired result right?

Comment: Yes. $|a_9|=\frac{1}{9!}>10^{-6}>\frac{1}{10!}=|a_{10}|$, so $n=10$ is the answer.